# msg.sender not increasing the balance

Tags: solidity, transactions

I am trying to execute the following code obtained from`[Solidity Tutorial](https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/solidity-tutorial)

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;
contract ERC20Token {
    string name;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function mint() payable public {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;//use tx.origin, 
    }
}
contract MyContract {
    address public token;

    address payable wallet;

    constructor(address payable _wallet, address _token) public {
        wallet = _wallet;
        token = _token;
    }
    function() external payable{
       buyToken();
    }
    function buyToken() public payable {
        ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token));
        _token.mint();
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

The tutorial says that I have to use tx.origin instead of msg.sender but tx.origin is a vulnerability. Somebody please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What are the intentions of this? What is the expected behavior? It's hard to answer without knowing what should actually happen

Comment: I'm not sure I would spend time on a tutorial that is recommending known security risks. It's better to learn good patterns and best practices from the beginning, IMO.

Comment: I have also heard that tx.origin is recommended for removal. I am following this tutorial because its giving some meat for using remix ide. But I would highlight anything vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that msg.sender is advised over tx.origin. The reason this isn't working is because you aren't sending any ETH with the `mint()` call, so it's 0, and the token balance isn't increasing. It's hard to understand the intended outcome, but you'd probably want to have `mint` only be callable by `MyContract`, and have `mint` take a parameter and called as `_token.mint(msg.value)`, then use that parameter as the number of tokens.

Comment: I have changed the mint() function to:  function mint(uint no_of_tokens) payable public {
        balances[msg.sender] += no_of_tokens;
    }, and the buyToken function is: function buyToken() public payable {
        ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token));
        _token.mint(msg.value);
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    } , but stiil I am getting zero balance, somebody please guide me. Zulfi.

Comment: @zak100 Your issue now is that msg.sender in `mint` is the MyContract account. `mint` should also take an address to mint to, or MyContract should transfer the tokens to msg.sender after minting.